# Raspberry pi usb permissions

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can only get output from a connected usb robot arm when I run my Python script in sudo. I assume I need to give normal user permission for the usb device. How would I do this?

Comment: Thanks mark.. A newbie with the pi so don't fully follow... Any idea where I should start?

Comment: It's the maplin robot arm. I put a camera and battery on it, wrote a python script to run it which works fine when run locally as sudo. When I ssh in from another pi (the one I'm going to use as remote) I can't run the script as sudo, it says X11 is not authenticated. The idea I had then was to run is as a normal user. That launches the application but it says the USB port permission isn't there!!! I can't seem to win.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I believe that is working- as I see the gui when run as a normal user, it only happens when I run it with sudo... Or a I missing the point..

Comment: Thanks mark- I appreciate all your help